# CentOS USER_CMD logs auditd

Tags: centos, logging, pam, root, auditd

We are trying to start logging all executed commands by users (including root) on CentOS using auditd with type=USER_CMD, how we can do it?

We already getting commands, starting with sudo, but not others.

Auditd setting, which allow us to login sudo actions:

```
-w /var/log/sudo.log -p wa -k actions
-w /etc/sudoers -p wa -k scope
```

But how can we log ALL commands, that executed via shell from ALL users?